# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime (Int64 to datetime)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Trying

`SELECT convert(datetime, 20120825142616 , 120) AS time`

Running into exception

*Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.*

The value '20120825142616 ' **is of type 'Int64**' passed as parameter to a .Net SqlCommand object.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place your data in single quote then you will not get arithmetic flow error

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '20120825142616' , 120) AS [time]
```

but you will got an error:

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

I thought the format is not right. If I only place date it works. like

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '20120825' , 120) AS [time]
-- output
2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
```

and If I place date in this format it works

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '2012-08-25 14:26:16' , 120) AS [time]
-- output
2012-08-25 14:26:16.000
```

Comment: this gives similar details  http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/